# Why is this point analytic?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analyticity

Suppose you had the function
$$
p(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}
$$
I know, from other material online, that this point is analytic at the point $x=0$. However, my understanding was that a point of a function is analytic if it's differentiable at that point. The derivative of this function is
$$
p'(x) = \frac{x \; \cos(x) - \sin(x)}{x^{2}}
$$
Which is clearly undefined at the point $x=0$.

So why have I seen people saying that $x=0$ is an analytic point for this function?

Comment: Technically, that function $p$ is also not defined at $x=0$. It can be made continuous by defining it as $1$ at zero, and similarly, the functuion $p'$ you have can be made continuous at $x=0$. (If $p'(0)$ has a value, it would have to be zero, since $p(x)$ is a "even" function - $p(-x)=p(x)$.)

Comment: Consider the Taylor series $p(x)=\sum_0^\infty{(-x^2)^k/(2k+1)!}$, that has an infinite radius of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

As given the function $p$ is clearly not defined at $x=0$; and a fortiori it has no derivative there. But it is easily verified that
$$p(x)=\int_0^1\cos(tx)\>dt=:q(x)\qquad\forall\>x\ne0\ ,$$
whereby the function $q$ is defined on all of ${\mathbb R}$, and is easily seen to be $C^\infty$ on ${\mathbb R}$. It is then only natural to define $p(0):=q(0)=1$, which then makes $p$ defined and smooth on all of ${\mathbb R}$. This function is called ${\rm sinc}$, and plays an important rôle in signal processing.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What does the notation $=:$ mean though, and how is it different to $=$?

Comment: It means that the function $q$ is defined by said integral.